# React site giving 502 Bad Gateway on domain if npm start is not running, nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I am trying to make my react website work.
But the website does not load until npm start is initiated in the root directory. I need the website to work, even if I am not running npm start.

The package.json is:

```
    {
  "name": "XXXXX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "XXXXXXXX",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
    "build": "node index.js"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more background information.In what environment are you trying to run in? You work locally and expect changes to to your code to load up automatically without restarting the server etc... (try https://github.com/remy/nodemon )

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting it on for example Debian or Ubuntu with SystemD, you could create a Service file for that task.

Firstly you have to create a service file for that:

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/my-react-js-service.service
```

With the content:

```
[Unit]
Description=ReactJS Website Service
After=network.target
After=nginx.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=www-data
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/<your-code-directory>
ExecStart=npm start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The working directory needs to be the directory in wich you normally run `npm start` and the user must be the user with whom you normally run `npm start`. Be sure that the user has enough permissions in the working directory.

Now you have to reload SystemD:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

And finally start your Service:

```
systemctl start my-react-js-service.service
```

If you want, you can also start your service on startup with the following command:

```
systemctl enable my-react-js-service.service
```

Comment: Failed to start my-react-js-service.service: Unit my-react-js-service.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status my-react-js-service.service' for details.}

When I tried "sudo systemctl start my-react-js-service.service"

Comment: Can you try to replace `npm start` with `/bin/bash npm start` after the `ExecStart=`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm build` to create a production version of your site, that you can host on your server. This won't need `npm start` to work.

`npm build` will create a **build** directory. You need to take all of the files generated/copied inside and put them on your server.

You can read more about the process [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/).

Comment: npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-06-23T16_15_31_117Z-debug.log


What I get when I try this. Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe npm build?

Comment: build needs to be inserted into the package.json i think.

Comment: So you're not using `create-react-app` I guess then?
Could you edit your question and add more details about your project?

Comment: Edited and inserted the package.json what else could be needed?

Comment: @asifhossain Where are your react dependencies?